# Generate Paginated PDF from UIWebView

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, printing

I've got a UIWebView that I'm using to display a stylized NSString of HTML that I'm generating.  I'd like to be able to email a paginated PDF of the displayed page.

Right now, I can use the iOS 4.0 printing features to print a nice, paginated representation of all the text in the UIWebView.  Can I do the same, but rather than print the PDF, generate an NSData object (or a file in the sandboxed file system) from the HTML string?

I can already generate an image of the UIWebView, but this doesn't paginate easily and requires a lot more work than I think should be necessary to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Ever figured this out? I kind of need it too!